# Strange form behaviour in Twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a form that I display row by row in Twig. On a particular row, I try to pass HTML attributes as options, like this :

```
{{ form_row(form.classic_text, {'attr': {'class': 'test'}}) }}
```

The option is passed to the form, as I can see the class being applied to the form. However, when I put a dump right after the above code, like this :

```
{{ form_row(form.classic_text, {'attr': {'class': 'test'}}) }}
{{ dump(form.classic_text) }}
```

the `attr` array is empty. Any idea why ? Thanks for reading, I can provide more information in needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it's just because you are trying to access the `attr` array outside the scope where it exists

Comment: But what is this scope exaclty ? Because I try to access it right after I set it, I imagined it would be the same ...

Comment: This scope - function form_row() you are calling above. Think of this like you're doing something like this in PHP code:

form_row($form['classic_text'], array('attrs' => ['class' => 'test']));
var_dump($form['classic_text']);

Comment: OK, I just thought that once you had written the `attr` array, behind the scene it was setting the HTML form attributes right away. Thanks for the clarification